# Error in code; Getting wrong summation output

Tags: c, function, loops, factorial

I have to compute e^(x) using taylor series and error bound. We were instructed to make 3 separate functions, then use them to compute e^(x) with an accuracy and x value that the user inputs. The compiler finally compiles the code, however if I enter x=2, and delta=(anything), I get sum=3.000 instead of 7.3890. Im assuming its my final loop (sum loops) that has the error. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float power(float A, int B)
{
    float sum=1.0;
    int nterms=1;

    while ( nterms <= B && B > 0) 
    {
        sum = A*sum;
        nterms++;
    }

    return sum;
}

int factorial(int b)
{
    int fact=1;

    while (b >= 2) 
    {
        fact = b*(b-1)*fact;
        b = b-2;
    }

    return fact;    
}

int Terms(float X, float a)
{
    int N=1,l;
    float L,R;

    l=N+1;

    while (L < a && a <= R)
    {
        L= (power(X,l)/(factorial(l)));
        R= (power(X,N)/(factorial(N)));
        N++;
    }

    return N;
}

int main()
{

    float x, delta, term=0.0, sum=0.0;
    int n, Nterms;

    printf("Please enter a decimal number. x=");
    scanf("%f",x);
    printf("Please enter an another number. delta=");
    scanf("%d",delta);


    Nterms=Terms(x,delta);

    for(n=0;n<Nterms;n++)
    {
        if( n==0 || n==1 )
        {
            sum = 1 + x;
        }
        else if (n>=2 && n<Nterms)
        {
            sum = sum + term;
            term = (power(x,n))/(factorial(n));
        }   
    }

    printf("The approximation for e^(%f)=%f",x,sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `scanf("%d",delta);` to  `scanf("%f",&delta);`

Comment: Ah thank you! I ran it again and it still closed the compiler without compiling, but im one step in the right direction! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
scanf("%f",x);
scanf("%d",delta);
```

to

```
scanf("%f", &x);
scanf("%f", &delta);
```

Error was in how you read the user input. `scanf()` will read on to the location pointed by the pointer.

Comment: Ah thank you!! It compiles now!!! However there must be some kind of problem with my final loop, it prints the sum as 1 + x, but ignores the    else if (n>=2)

Comment: print the value of `Nterms` before the loop. Also `else if (n>=2 && n<Nterms)` is not required. Just a `else` would do.

Comment: Okay! Thank you! A bit confused as to what you mean by print value of Nterms before the loop, what part of the code were you looking at, and what does that do?

Comment: After this statement ` Nterms=Terms(x,delta);` write `printf("Nterms = %d\n", Nterms);` so as to debug why your code `else if (n >= 2) is ignored`

Comment: Okay! I'll try it and post the results! Thank you!

Comment: Nterms = 1 for everything I put in, so that helps locate the error!